# FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_SOFT_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK

Tags: drivers, hard-disk, disk, scsi

What does it mean DID_SOFT_ERROR?

According to kernel source, it defined:

```
#define DID_SOFT_ERROR  0x0b    /* The low level driver just wish a retry  */
```

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/6cdc577a18a616c331f57e268c97466171cfc45f/include/scsi/scsi.h#L147

and

```
    case SAS_QUEUE_FULL:
        hs = DID_SOFT_ERROR; /* retry */
        break;
```

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/c6dd78fcb8eefa15dd861889e0f59d301cb5230c/drivers/scsi/libsas/sas_scsi_host.c#L63

Does it mean the SAS HDD's internal queue full then caused this error?